# Codesigning PHP 8 in Monterey

Tags: macos, monterey, php, code-signing

Following this guide: [How to sign homebrew PHP module in macOS](https://www.simplified.guide/macos/apache-php-homebrew-codesign#commento-login-box-container)

I'm stuck on step five:

> **Locate location or path of PHP module from Apache's PHP LoadModule directive.**
>
> ```
> $ grep -nir "^loadmodule.*php" /etc/apache2
> /etc/apache2/other/00-httpd.conf:4:LoadModule php7_module >/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
> ```

I keep running into the error:

> ```
> zsh: no such file or directory: /etc/apache2/other/00->httpd.conf:4:LoadModule
> ```

I've located my install of PHP at the following path:

> /usr/local/opt/php@8.1/8.1.0_3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

But it seems to be some sort of error with /etc/apache2/other/00->httpd.conf - there doesn't even seem to be a httpd.conf file at that location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone on an Intel chip runs into the same problem, the way I solved this in the end:

- Skip step 5
- Go straight to step 6 and codesigning it at this location: >/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
- Also: Nothing is generally located in the "other" folder, i.e.: /etc/apache2/other/00-httpd.conf
- Instead use /etc/apache2/00-httpd.conf